# RMI call to my session bean using Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, weblogic, rmi

Can someone give me a code snippet in which I could perform an RMI call to my session bean (written in Java and deployed on Weblogic) in Groovy?

**Edit 1**

This is my java code. Is there any easier way to do it in Groovy?

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
props.put("java.naming.provider.url",”t3://127.0.0.1:7001”);  // url+port format
props.put("java.naming.security.principal", “weblogic_username”));
props.put("java.naming.security.credentials", “weblogic_password”);
try
{
     String simpleName = MyRemoteClass.class.getSimpleName();
     String fullName = MyRemoteClass.class.getName();
     String name = simpleName + "#" + fullName;
     initContext = new InitialContext(props);
     MyRemoteClass remoteClass = (MyRemoteClass)initContext.lookup(name);

     remoteClass.doSomething();
} 
catch (Throwable ex) 
{
}
```

Comment: It would be pretty much the same, only you can benefit from some syntax sugar. What have you tried?

Comment: @WillP I added my java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about any library to wrap/ease RMI calls from Groovy. If there's none, you can at least benefit from syntactic sugar, coercion and implicit casting:

```
def props = [
  "java.naming.factory.initial" : "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory",
  "java.naming.provider.url" : "t3://127.0.0.1:7001",  // url+port format
  "java.naming.security.principal" : "weblogic_username",
  "java.naming.security.credentials" : "weblogic_password"
] as Properties

try
{
     def name = "${MyRemoteClass.simpleName}#${MyRemoteClass.name}"
     initContext = new InitialContext(props)
     MyRemoteClass remoteClass = initContext.lookup name

     remoteClass.doSomething()
} 
catch (t)
{
  t.printStackTrace()
}
```

Groovy :-)

Comment: Thanks. But it is Java. I was looking for something easier. :--)

Comment: What do you mean "it is Java"?

Comment: I mean I am looking for something easier than the mentioned code.